# Show progress bar while the shellexecute command executes batch file in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005

What I am doing is executing a batch file through shellexecute command, now what I want is to show a progress bar or just a status as "In Progress" and disable all the other controls on the dialog. How can we achieve that in MFC.

Currently what I do is just use **WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);** which shows my application as hanged(not actually) till the batch file finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a worker thread that manages the executing a batch file and posts a message to a main (GUI) thread when ready.

Answer (score 0):

- As soon as user initiates the action - disable all control (all desired controls). And launch a thread.
- The thread will call `ShellExecute`[`Ex`] or `CreateProcess`. Hold the handle of process and call `WaitForSingleObject` with `INFINITE` time.
- As soon as WFSO returns, notify the window (the dialog, the form - whatsoever), that process has finished.
  -

In order to notify the window of *completion*, you may have to define a custom message code:

```
#define WM_PROCESS_FINISHED (WM_APP + 10)
```

Write entry for `WM_PROCESS_FINISHED` in message-loop, or message-map.

From the thread, just call `PostMessage` (or `SendMessage`) with target-window's handle and this message code:

```
PostMessage(hTargetWnd, WM_PROCESS_FINISHED);
```